# Search Special Character From Search Box with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search").keyup(function(){

   seaarch_str=$("#search").val();
    alert(seaarch_str);

             $.ajax({
    url:"search_live_ajax.php",
      type:"GET",
   data:"search_string="+seaarch_str,
success:function(data){
 $("#detail").html(data);
 }
});
     });
    });
```

I want to search A+,A-, but it is not showing results of A+ but their is value in the database.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to "HtmlEncode" text. Could you add more details about javascript Ajax call ?

Comment: Can you please Post your code what you are trying.

Comment: Use `data: {search_string: seaarch_str}` so that it is URL encoded correctly

Comment: Very Very Thanks For your suggestion.It works!!!!.